# how to stop recovering to original value when animation stopped

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I use core animation to make a view animated. When animation stopped, the view will recover to it's original value. How can I stop recovering?
Here is my code

```
   #define p(x,y) CGPointMake(x,y)
   #define v valueWithCGPoint
    ...
    CGPoint rectL=p(463, 473);
    CGPoint rectR=p(503, 473);
    NSValue *valueL = [NSValue v:rectL];
    NSValue *valueR = [NSValue v:rectR];
    NSArray *firstArray=@[valueL,valueR,valueL,valueR,valueL,valueR,valueL,valueR];

    CAKeyframeAnimation * theAnimation;

    // Create the animation object, specifying the position property as the key path.
    theAnimation=[CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    theAnimation.values=firstArray;
    theAnimation.duration=5.0;
    //theAnimation.calculationMode= kCAAnimationLinear;
    // Add the animation to the layer.
    [self.boView.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"moveBackAndForth"];
```

Comment: So when the animation *ends*, `position` is **not** `(503, 473)`? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: @Mar0ux not (503, 473),it recovers to original value.

Comment: I think you're doing something wrong. This isn't supposed to happen. Are you sure you're checking the value *in*/*after* the completion block? Do you have any other animation running? Is some other piece of code overriding these properties: `frame`/`position`/`center` etc?

Comment: @Mar0ux removedOnCompletion's default value is YES.Now I change it to NO,but it still not works.

Comment: that's because `removedOnCompletion` has nothing to do with this :) Pl check my last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the final value before you add the animation. The animation includes the desired start value so it will continue to work as you desire.

Comment: Add [yourAnimation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];

Answer (score 0):

set the **CAKeyframeAnimation** property `removedOnCompletion = NO;`

```
theAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
```